# How can I validate a bound object who's validation requires knowledge of other objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a small gui with a listbox. The listbox is bound to a collection. The user can edit an item in the collection using an "Edit" window.

The Edit window is bound to the selected object in the listbox. One of the validations I need to perform is to make sure the user does not enter a name for an item which has already been used (meaning it can't be used by any of the other objects in the listbox).

Is there a good way to do this with WPF validation?

Answer (score 1):

The item you are validating must provide reference to a parent object (collection).
When you have parent collection, the rest is simple, and I think, got nothing to do with WPF.

Take a look at the [Enforcing parent-child relationship in C# and .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982796/enforcing-parent-child-relationship-in-c-sharp-and-net)