# Is there a way to trigger some kind of `OnPropertyChanged` event for a computed property that uses a property of a "child entity" in a collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, entity, inotifycollectionchanged

Is there a way to trigger some kind of `OnPropertyChanged` event for a computed property that uses a property of a "child entity" in a collection?

A small example:

I have a simple  WPF application with a DataGrid showing Customer properties.
I am using Entity Framework 5, CodeFirst approach, so I wrote my classes manually with my own INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

```
public partial class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstName;
    public virtual string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    private string _lastName;
    public virtual string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Now in that same class I created 3 computed properties:

```
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return (FirstName + " " + LastName).Trim(); }
    }

    public int TotalCars
    {
        get
        {
            return Cars.Count();
        }
    }

    public int TotalOpenInvoices
    {
        get
        {
            if (Invoices != null)
                return (from i in Invoices
                        where i.PayedInFull == false
                        select i).Count();
            else return 0;
        }
    }
```

The `FullName` is automatically updated in the DataGrid because I'm calling `OnPropertyChanged("FullName");`

I found an example of the INotifyCollectionChanged implementation that I can probably use to auto update the `TotalCars` when something is added to or removed from the ICollection:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article886-change-notification-for-objects-and-collections.aspx

But what is the best approach to trigger the `OnPropertyChange("TotalOpenInvoices")` when a property (`PayedInFull`) inside the ICollection (`Invoices`) changes?

Doing something like `OnPropertyChanged("Customer.TotalOpenInvoices");` in the Invoice class doesn't seem to do the trick... :)

Comment: You can call the property changed of of customer.

Comment: This particular problem is what led me to end up creating my own MVVM framework

Comment: You can either use the manual approach.. or start playing around with Expression Trees in order to find out in which instance you must raise the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have control of what goes inside your collections? If you do, you can create a Parent property on your Invoice object and when it is added to the collection, set the parent to your Customer. Then when PaidInFull gets set, run your Customer.OnPropertyChanged("TotalOpenInvoices") or call a method on the Customer object to recalculate your invoices.

[Enforcing parent-child relationship in C# and .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982796/enforcing-parent-child-relationship-in-c-sharp-and-net)

Comment: @HighCore +1 to you then. I wasn't quite sure what you were referring to by it.

Comment: Thanks, anyways I always suggest to make these kind of things as generic and reusable as possible, that's why I told you about the expression trees.

Comment: @HighCore Please make an answer for it. It will help ivanv and anyone else who may see this question. I have not used Expression Trees so I cannot comment on it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! In my Invoice class I already have a Customer navigation property that Entity Framework uses to connect the classes together. So that's actually my Parent property. Instead of calling OnPropertyChanged("Customer.TotalOpenInvoices") in my Invoice class, I just changed it to Customer.OnPropertyChanged("TotalOpenInvoices")... I did have to change the OnPropertyChanged from "protected" to "internal". But now it works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Expression Trees aswell. I will check that out also :)

Comment: For me the navigation property is always null. Maybe is that the object is not saved yet?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that Invoice and Customer both implement IPropertyChanged.  Simply change your collection to an ObservableCollection, and watch the CollectionChanged property.

When new Invoices are added, hook up an event handler to the PropertyChanged event of that Invoice.  When an item is removed from the collection, remove that event handler.

Then, just call your NotifyPropertyChanged function on your TotalOpenInvoices property.

For example (not completely tested, but it should be close):

**Invoice**

```
public class Invoice : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private bool payedInFull = false;
        public bool PayedInFull
        {
            get { return payedInFull; }
            set
            {
                payedInFull = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PayedInFull");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**Customer**

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Invoices.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Invoices_CollectionChanged);
    }

    ObservableCollection<Invoice> Invoices 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int TotalOpenInvoices
    {
        get
        {
            if (Invoices != null)
                return (from i in Invoices
                        where i.PayedInFull == false
                        select i).Count();
            else return 0;
        }
    }


    void Invoices_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Invoice invoice in e.NewItems)
        {
            invoice.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(invoice_PropertyChanged);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalOpenInvoices");
        }

        foreach (Invoice invoice in e.OldItems)
        {
            invoice.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(invoice_PropertyChanged);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalOpenInvoices");
        }
    }

    void invoice_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "PayedInFull")
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalOpenInvoices");
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that each class could be abstracted to a single class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, such as a ViewModelBase class, but that is not necessarily required for this example.