# What good workarounds are there for using the 'this' keyword in a constructor?

Tags: c#

<strike>Suppose I have a class `ParentClass` and a class `ChildClass` laid out like this:</strike>

```cs
public class ParentClass
{
    readonly List<ChildClass> children = new List<ChildClass>();
    public ParentClass()
    {
        children.Add(new ChildClass(this, 856));
        children.Add(new ChildClass(this, 734));
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    readonly ParentClass parent;
    readonly int value;
    public ChildClass(ParentClass parent, int value)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This won't work, because you cannot use the 'this' keyword in the context I used it at in the constructor of `ParentClass`. What are the possible workarounds for getting a parent member like this assigned in the constructor?

So it seems in my attempt to generalize the question, I removed the error. If there are any moderators out there who know better how to deal with a mistake like this (instead of striking through the whole thing) please feel free to fix it. The way I had my classes laid out more closely resembles this:

```cs
public class ParentTemplate : ParentClass
{
    public ParentTemplate() : base(new ChildClass(this, 856), new ChildClass(this, 734))
    {

    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
    readonly List<ChildClass> children = new List<ChildClass>();

    public ParentClass(params ChildClass[] children)
    {
        foreach(ChildClass child in children)
        {
            this.children.Add(child);
        }
    }
}

public class ChildClass
{
    readonly ParentClass parent;
    readonly int value;
    public ChildClass(ParentClass parent, int value)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In this case, the 'this' parameter does give an error, which is the problem I'm trying to circumvent.

Comment: In what way can you not use `this` in that context? Its use is discouraged but it compiles ok.

Comment: I do use the pattern of using this.*, as I find it has good readability for both variable names to be the same, but it comes with a pitfall: when you misspell the variable in the parameter list, it won't throw an error. E.g. using ChildClass(ParentClass parrent, int vallue) would work, because the below parent and value occurrences will then quietly be considered to represent class properties, resulting in quietly non-working code (I would need to check if it at least throws an "unused variable" warning at least, it might).

Comment: *"you cannot use the `this` keyword in the context I used it at in the constructor of ParentClass"*. Yes you can - I just copy/pasted your code into a new project, did an assignment `var x = new ParentClass();`. No compile errors. Set a breakpoint and ran the code. `x` has two children, just as expected.

Comment: @Lee It gives the compile error of "CS0027 Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context" so it doesn't compile ok

Comment: The code in your question compiles for me as expected.

Comment: That is really weird, I'm gonna look into what I'm doing wrong then.

Comment: Side-note: Consider sending integer values as constructor parameters, or - if they are fixed values - defining them as constants.

Comment: @Suhbahstiejaan You cannot use `this` in the base constructor call because you are still "building" the object you want to create. This would be a chicken-egg-problem. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982796/enforcing-parent-child-relationship-in-c-sharp-and-net? Why does your constructors have the type of the other class? How do you plan to create one object first without having the other types object, which would require having the first object you want to create in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the children into a property and initialize lazily. Always access the children through the property, not the field.

```
public class ParentClass
{
    private List<ChildClass> _children;
    private List<ChildClass> Children
    {
        get {
            if (_children == null) {
                _children = new List<ChildClass> {
                    new ChildClass(this, 856),
                    new ChildClass(this, 734)
                };
            }
            return _children;
        }
    }
}
```

I was also considering using a `Lazy<List<ChildClass>>`, but using the `this` keyword in the factory lambda in the field initializer doesn't work either.

---

I adapted my solution to your edit. The trick is to pass a function delegate to the constructor for the initialization of the children.

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass(Func<ParentClass, IEnumerable<ChildClass>> createChildren)
    {
        children = new List<ChildClass>(createChildren(this));
    }

    private readonly List<ChildClass> children;
}
```

The base initialization then goes like this:

```
public class ParentTemplate : ParentClass
{
    public ParentTemplate()
        : base(p => new[] { new ChildClass(p, 856), new ChildClass(p, 734) })
    {

    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can let the delegate return a `List<ChildClass>` directly.

---

Another approach is to only pass the values and let the parent class create the children

```
public ParentClass(params int[] values)
{
    children = values.Select(v => new ChildClass(this, v)).ToList();
}
```

If you have more parameters, you can use [Value Tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/)

```
public ParentClass(params (int, string)[] values)
```

the constructor can then be called like this

```
var p = new ParentClass((856, "hello"), (734, "world"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to try to implement an `Abstract Factory Method`. You protected the `constructor` and make an method avaliable to make an object of this class (`static` and public`), for sample:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    readonly List<ChildClass> children = new List<ChildClass>();
    private ParentClass()
    {
    }

    public static ParentClass Create()
    {
        var parent = new ParentClass();
        parent.children.Add(new ChildClass(parent, 856));
        parent.children.Add(new ChildClass(parent, 734));

        return parent;
    }
}
```